Behaviour of one-side socket close for UNIX socket with SOCK_DGRAM vs. SOCK_STREAM
When closing a UNIX socket on one side I would expect the other side to be notified of that by a read call, that returns 0. However when using SOCK_DGRAM, the read-call blocks indefinitely. Even when using MSG_DONTWAIT, it will just return EINTR over and over again.
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define SIZE 16

int main (void)
{
    int sockets[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char buffer[SIZE];

    assert (0 == socketpair (AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0, sockets));

    pid = fork();
    assert (pid >= 0);

    /* client */
    if (0 == pid)
    {
        close (sockets[0]);
        close (sockets[1]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    /* server */
    else
    {
        close (sockets[1]);
        read (sockets[0], buffer, SIZE);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}

(This does indeed work, when replacing SOCK_DGRAM with SOCK_STREAM.)
Why doesn't the read call return? Where is that specified (haven't found anything)?
How is one supposed to notice when using SOCK_DGRAM, that the other side has closed the socket?

Datagram sockets aren't connection oriented; there's thus no notification to be made. If you want that and you're using Linux, look into SOCK_SEQPACKET sockets.

If TCP connections are like telephone calls, then datagram sockets are like the postal service.  You can send and receive parcels, but the post office won't notify you when your pen-pal has closed out his post office box.

@JeremyFriesner Considering, that it is not about networking, I would still have expected, that reading from an unexisting address would give an error, as it would for other files.

You're not reading from an unexisting address, though -- the address of your unclosed local socket remains valid, and your socket even could still receive packets if there was something out there that knew how to send them to it.  It's the other socket that has been closed, not the one that you are reading from (and the two sockets aren't "connected" in any meaningful sense of the word, because datagrams don't work that way -- rather they just each have been set with a default destination address to use when send() or write() is called).


When closing a UNIX socket on one side I would expect the other side to be notified of that by a read call, that returns 0. However when using SOCK_DGRAM, the read-call blocks indefinitely. Even when using MSG_DONTWAIT, it will just return EINTR over and over again.

Yes. datagram sockets provide a connectionless protocol, so one side closing its socket does not involve any notification to the other side that that side might use to conclude that no more data will be coming.  In fact, more data could be coming from the same host and port, and at the UDP level, there is no way to distinguish that as a logically distinct sequence of messages.
With respect to the socket API, connect()ing a datagram socket merely sets its default destination address.  That's useful for using it with send() or write(), but you can use that socket both before and after connect()ing to send messages to other destinations via sendto() or sendmsg().

How is one supposed to notice when using SOCK_DGRAM, that the other side has closed the socket?

You can't. Datagram-based application protocols that need a sense of an ongoing connection need to layer that on top, possibly with a heartbeat signal, an "are you there?" message, and / or timeouts.  None of those detect remote socket closure directly, though, nor are they necessarily disrupted by remote socket closure.
If you want connections that are managed at the network protocol level, by the system, then use a stream socket or, if your system supports it, a sequential-packet socket.  This applies to AF_INET and AF_INET6 sockets, too.

Unix domain sockets do not use UDP. Same general idea though.

@JohnBollinger I was explicitly asking about UNIX sockets.

However, when writing it is known, that the connection is closed, because it returns ECONNREFUSED. Is there a way to determine that explicitly without writing?

@Caulder, it is substantially the same answer from the UNIX protocol suite as it is for the IP suite.  I have updated.

@Caulder, you cannot successfully write to a closed socket.  You can write to an open socket whose remote peer is closed, in which case the data are probably lost, and, depending on the socket type, you might or might not get an indication of it.  But the question posed was about reading.

What was the sequential-packet-type socket you mentioned earlier?

SOCK_SEQPACKET.  Some details are provided on the socket(2) manual page.

Does there also exist an option for AF_INET, because you mentioned it earlier for TCP?

Yes, @Caulder.  Linux supports SOCK_SEQPACKET over IPv4 and IPv6 networks via TCP and TCP6, respectively.  Support by other operating systems may vary.

Closure behavior: see the close(2) manual page, which says it "closes a file descriptor, so that it no longer refers to any file".  The "file" there should be understood in UNIX's expansive "everything is a file" sense.  Other details are spread more diffusely over a variety of manual pages.

I think I mainly got confused from On success, the number of bytes read is returned (zero indicates end of file), ... read(2), thinking that it applies always, but recv(2) clearly states, that When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).

Yes, @Caulder, the Devil is in the details.  That provision does not apply to datagram sockets.

Do you mean like this, @Caulder? Use the backquote character, just like you can do for inline code quoting in a question or answer.

Is there a way to check, like I asked in the third comment?

Why is the RefCnt displayed by netstat 3, when connected and 2 when disconnected?

@Caulder, the socket API does not provide a means to determine whether a socket's peer has been closed, other than by attempting to write to it (which may or may not provoke an error or return a characteristic return value).  Any other means that may be available are outside the scope of this Q&A.

@JohnBollinger Can you mention some related methods for that, and I can open a new question?

A dirty way to check it seams to be write(fd, NULL, 0). Do you think it is portable though?

No, @Caulder, that does not appear to be portable.  The POSIX specifications are a fairly good measure of portability.  They say of write the if the number bytes to be transferred is 0, and if the file descriptor refers to a regular file (which a socket is not), then implementations may perform error checks.  You cannot portably rely on that to happen, both because it is optional behavior as far as POSIX is concerned, and because your socket is not a regular file.
